Show that $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^x f(t)dx=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t)dt. $
Let $f(x)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $T$ (i.e., $f(x)=f(x+T)$). Assume that $\int_0^T |f(x)|dx<\infty$. Show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^x f(t)dx=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t)dt.
$$

I read the proof but I am confused about the following step: for every $\epsilon>0$, choose $n_0$ so that $1/(n_0T)<\epsilon/(2M)$ where $M:=\int_0^T |f(x)|dx$. For $n_0T<x\le (n_0+1)T$,
$$
|\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^x f(t)dx-\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t)dt|=|\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^x f(t)dx-\frac{1}{n_0T}\int_0^{n_0T} f(t)dt|
$$
$$
\le\frac{1}{x}\int_{n_0T}^x |f(t)|dt+n_0|\frac{x-n_0T}{xn_0T}|\int_0^T |f(t)|dt\le \frac{M}{x}+M\frac{x-n_0T}{xT}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+M\frac{T}{xT}=\epsilon...
$$
How do we get this equality? It seems that we let $y=n_0t$ in the second integral? Also, how do we get the above inequality?

Let $m = \displaystyle\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t) d t$ and for $x\ge 0$
\begin{equation}
g(x)= \int_{-x}^x (f(t)-m) d t
\end{equation}
then $g$ is periodic with period $T$, and for $x\in [0, T]$, one has
\begin{equation}
|g(x)|\le \int_{-T}^T |f(t)-m| d t = 2K
\end{equation}
by periodicity, this inequality holds for all $x\ge 0$ hence
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{1}{2 x}\int_{-x}^x f(t) d t - m\right|
=\left|\frac{1}{2 x} g(x)\right|
\le \frac{K}{x}\longrightarrow 0
\end{equation}

So what is your $K$? And how to get $|g(x)|\le 2K$ for all $x$?

@Hermi I define $K$  as $\int_0^T |f(t) - m| d t$. We have $|g(x)|\le 2 K$ for all $x\ge 0$ because it is true for $x\in [0, T]$ and $g$ is $T$-periodic.

We could also argue that $g$ is periodic and continuous, which implies immediately that it is bounded.

So for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we can write it $x=kT+q$ for some positive integers $k\ge 1$ and $0\le q <T$? So it holds for $x\in [0,T]$, then $g$ is bounded for any $x\ge 0$?

If $x\ge 0$ we have $x = k T + q$ for some $k\ge 0$ and $q\in [0, T)$. Hence $|g(x)| = |g(q)|\le 2K$.
